# How do I bind an input to a random generated number?

Tags: python, random, dice

I am trying to make a little minigame, where you can roll 6 dices, next you will be asked which dice kind you want to keep, lets say it generated this:

> > > 1,1,2,5,1,3

Now I want to user to for instance select the number 1 via raw_input, and let him roll again untill the he gets no more dices of the number 1

How do I let the user select the number he wants and let him roll again? (correct me if I am not asking to right question, I am still learning python)

```
import os
os.system('clear')

print (20 * '-')
print ("   dobbelsteen gooien")
print (20 * '-')
print ("1. Spel spelen")
print ("2. Stoppen")
print (20 * '-')
keuze = raw_input("Kies uit 1 of 2: ")
os.system('clear')
keuze = int(keuze)

if keuze == 1:
    import random
    for roll in xrange(6):
        dobbel = random.randint(1,6)
        if dobbel == 1:
            print "1"
        if dobbel == 2:
            print "2"
        if dobbel == 3:
            print "3"
        if dobbel == 4:
            print "4"
        if dobbel == 5:
            print "5"
        if dobbel == 6:
            print "6"

Een = 0
Twee = 0
Drie = 0
Vier = 0
Vijf = 0
Zes = 0
Zeven = 0
Acht = 0
Negen = 0
Tien = 0
Elf = 0
Twaalf = 0


print (20 * '-')
dobbel1 = input("Welke dobbelsteen wil je houden?: ")
if dobbel == 1 and dobbel1 == 1:
    Een = +1
    print "Je hebt nu %s van Een" % (dobbel)
```

Comment: Storing the rolls in a list lets you find the nth roll at index n-1 of that list. You can test if the list contains a particular value with the `in`-operator

Comment: What i would do i bind each dice to a variable (most likely to elements of a list) and assign the random elements (the rolls) to those variables. I would store the input from the user, roll again, and keep the variables inside the list which are equal to the input

Comment: Mostly unrelated, but in the dobbel area with all the print statements, why don't you just say "print dobbel"?